# How to evaluate a HMM model?

Tags: hidden-markov-model, measurement, model-evaluation

Imagine that one has learned the parameters for a HMM model (λ=(A,B,π)). 
How can I evaluate or even measure the accuracy of my model?

In classification models, it is straightforward and one can use F1, AUC and Accuracy. But here in HMM models. I am not quite sure what should I do?

Thanks everyone
I love Cross Validated site and I am very happy for being here :)

Comment: you can check the likelihood in testing data set.

Comment: @hxd1011 thank you very much! could you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: Sure, I am planing to write a long answer with demos, when I get time. Remember upvote me :)

Comment: @hxd1011 I appreciate your attention ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two major methods for evaluating a Hidden Markov Model (HMM).

1- Likelihood of test data:

In this approach, one should keep some test data and compute the likelihood of the test sequences by using the forward algorithm.

2- Predicting parts of data given other parts:

A meaningful prediction task depends on the application. For example, you may be interested in predicting the future. In this case, you can use forward algorithm to track the state of the hmm (i.e. compute P(X_t = i | o_1,o_2,o_t,pi) where X_t is the state at time t and o is the observation, and use that to predict the expected observation at some future time t+k. Do that for all t and compute the mean error.

By the way a very useful reference for learning about forward-backward algorithm would be [This note](https://people.csail.mit.edu/rameshvs/content/hmms.pdf). Some detailed instructions both about HMM and other PGM models can be found in Koller's book of Probabilistic Graphical Models.

Comment: I trained a second order hidden markov model and Baum Welch markov model for OCR typos correction.  What are the metrics to evaluate the  accuracy of my model